# Favorite tags selection in navigation bar & feed for android app

Tags: feature-request, android-app, android-app-feed

When using the web interface, there is a favorite tags section where you can select a list of tags that you view most frequently.

This has become a cornerstone of my normal [workflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191596/clicking-tag-in-question-should-present-a-list-of-questions) on stack overflow, but it doesn't look like this is possible in the Android app.

There should be a mechanism by which you can add some favorite tags to the nav bar. Clicking these tags will take you to a list of similarly tagged questions.

Perhaps also the feed should include a section for each favorite tag.  These would be presented on their own, much like how "hot new questions" and "new unanswered questions" appear in the feed.

Perhaps something like this:

[image]

Comment: The feed definitely could and will be improved in future iterations.

Comment: @ben: D'oh! My mistake. Didn't pay close enough attention.