# Clicking tag in question should present a list of questions

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, android-app

Another part of my daily [workflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191593/favorite-tags-selection-in-navigation-bar) on SE sites.  When viewing a question and it's time to move on, I'll often simply click one of the tags in the question to bring me back to a list of questions with that tag.

This doesn't work in the Android app.  Obligitory screenshot.  I tried to draw a finger that looked like it was tapping a tag, but it ended up looking like, well...  something else, let's say.

[image]

Comment: @CodyGray:  How did you do that?

Comment: You can add suffixes to the end of ImgUr file names. `s` for small, `m` for medium, and `l` for large. Easy way to resize.

Comment: @CodyGray: Neat.  Thanks

Comment: @Geoff is this still planned? :)

Comment: Also worth to mention that you can add `?s=[value]` to the imgur URL's to resize, it supports values like 28, 56, 128, 300, 500 and maybe more. [example](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Jn2YV.gif?s=300).

Answer (score 3):

This feature was added on 10/25/2013.