# Improve selection/ranking of favorite sites and feed for the android app

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, android-app, android-app-feed

It looks like the favorite sites are sorted by reputation and the feed picks up on this as well. Fair enough in general, but for me, it's definitely wrong. I used to be reasonably active on SO and am still accumulating plenty of reputation from old posts there, but now I'm primarily active on cooking. I can't actually tell whether it's using total reputation or recent gain; I still gain plenty from old posts on SO.

The favorite sites and feed should use recent activity for ranking, not just reputation.

(I found [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191593/favorite-tags-selection-in-navigation-bar-feed), but I'm definitely suggesting automated selection here, not manually curated tag sets.)

Answer (score 1):

We're definitely planning on tweaking how the feed chooses sites to "prefer".  Currently we're using reputation because it's readily available, but it's far from ideal as you point out.

There's actually a fairly large redesign of how the feed backend works to address some other issues (mostly around how the feed can "bunch up" lots of events, and doesn't expose anything that's not *really* recent) planned.  I'll probably be talking this issue afterwards, I'd say a week or two.