# Frequent tag shortcut in Android client

Tags: feature-request, android-app

It would really convenient if such shortcut exists. It may be placed in the left side menu after *Your Site* section and above *Others* section.

EDIT: After searching the meta, I found an *ancient* but interesting [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/191593/). I think this could be closed if the functionality involved in that question is implemented.